# *ngIf to show and hide div no longer working after applying data binding

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a form with a template that is used to either create a new form or load and edit an existing one.  I've applied data binding to radio button fieldsets to have them toggled according to the data coming from the database.  In doing that, the *ngIf's used to toggle other div's visibility no longer work for some reason.

Before (Visibility toggling works):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" formControlName="specificPilot" value="1" [ngClass]="{'td-radio-error': displayMessage.specificPilot}" (check)="radioSetValidator(changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot'),[changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.pilotTransits')])">Yes
        <input type="radio" formControlName="specificPilot" value="0" [ngClass]="{'td-radio-error': displayMessage.specificPilot}" (check)="radioSetValidator(changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot'),[changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.pilotTransits')])">No
        {{this.changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot').value}}
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" formControlName="pilotTransits" style="width:100%" placeholder="Provide Transits for Pilot(s)"
    *ngIf="changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot').value==='1'"></textarea>
</div>
```

After (data binding works, but visibility toggling does not):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
     <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" formControlName="specificPilot" [value]="1" [ngClass]="{'td-radio-error': displayMessage.specificPilot}" (check)="radioSetValidator(changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot'),[changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.pilotTransits')])">Yes
          <input type="radio" formControlName="specificPilot" [value]="0" [ngClass]="{'td-radio-error': displayMessage.specificPilot}" (check)="radioSetValidator(changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot'),[changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.pilotTransits')])">No
          {{this.changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot').value}}
     </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" formControlName="pilotTransits" style="width:100%" placeholder="Provide Transits for Pilot(s)"
     *ngIf="changeForm.get('generalQuestionsFG.specificPilot').value==='1'"> </textarea>
</div>
```

Would someone be able to explain why the *ngIf checking the radio button control's value isn't working anymore?  I added stubcode in to check if the value is changing properly and it is.

Comment: Your code is tough to read b/c there is lots of horizontal scrolling and extraneous info. Please consider removing unnecessary info.  Which line has the problematic `*ngIf`?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed the formatting, the second last line in both examples display the *ngIf.  The first example worked before I added databinding to the value property of both radio buttons, as shown in the third and fourth lines in the second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `<input value="1">`, the value will be string `"1"`.

When you do `<input [value]="1">`, the value will be number `1`.

You are comparing with strict equality so it breaks.